# Telerik Mvc Upload change style of remove button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

how can i change the text and icon of the "remove" button of telerik mvc Upload control?

Thks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API doesn't expose it, you'll have to examine the HTML output and use Javascript code to update it.  Or, I think the extensions return an IHtmlString (been a little since I've used them), which you can return the string, call ToHtmlString(), parse the string looking for "Remove" and replacing it with something else, then render out the modified results.

Comment: yes i was trying that but couldn't make i work because i was trying to change the delete button in the OnSucess Event. But when this event fired the t-delete didn't exist only the t-cancel. I solved it changing the html in the onComplete event. Thnks

Answer (score 1):

to change the icon was quite simple just added the following css:

```
#WindowUpload .t-icon.t-delete{
height:16px !important;
width:16px !important; 
background-position: -16px -336px !important;}
```

I was having trouble changing the text "Remove" because i was trying to change it in the OnSucess event, and the t-delete didn't exist yet (only the t-cancel). Making the change int the OnComplete event did the trick.

```
function OnComplete() {

$(".t-upload-action").first().text(" ").prepend("<span class='t-icon t-delete'>");}
```